# How to organize your sources (digital system)

Tags: sources, organization

I'm using an application to store and work on my research. I can have a source, with multiple entities referring to it. Each entity has a unique "page" for the source. Additionally each source can have multiple media items under it. So I have sources like:

- United States Census, 1920
- United States Census, 1930
- United States Census, 1940
- Pennsylvania Death Certificates
- Ohio Marriage Records
- Ohio Marriage Certificate
- Ohio Death Certificate

Under each source I have Media images labeled like:

- United States Census, 1930

  - Carnegie Ward 1, 15B
  - Pittsburgh Ward 12, 6B
  - Cleveland District 809, 10B
- Ohio Death Certificate

  - 1939, #44796
  - 1948, #67623
  - 1950, #66703

Each person/event is then sourced like:

- John Doe, Death

  - Ohio Death Certificate, Page: 1939, #44796
- Jane Doe, Death

  - Ohio Death Certificate, Page: 1948, #67623
- Mary Poppins, Census

  - United States Census, 1930, Page: Cleveland District 809, 10B

Is this OK? Should I be doing it different? I thought about having each item be a source `Ohio Death Certificate, Page: 1948, #67623` but then I would have a ton of sources in no real groups. Right now I'm at < 500 people and < 100 documents but I'm getting more documents each day. What so people with > 1000 people and documents do?

Answer (score 2):

There is a somewhat related question: [How should I organise my digital documents?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2945/how-should-i-organise-my-digital-documents)

For the specifics of your question, what you specify above is a good system and is just as I would do it.

If you feel you have too many individual sources, then you should group the sources by source type, e.g. Birth Records, Photos, Correspondence, Online, Interviews, etc., as I outline in [my answer to the other question where I recommend source-based folder organization](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2957/29).